# make some row editable and other row readonly on dhtmlx grid

Tags: dhtmlx

i want to make a row in dhtmlx are read only but i want make the other row are editable with some condition like
id%2=0 are editable.

```
function doInitGrid(){
        mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('mygrid_container');
        mygrid.selMultiRows = true;
        mygrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/");
        mygrid.setHeader("No, Id, Kd Dep, Kd Prog");
        mygrid.setInitWidths("30,50,60,60");
        mygrid.setColAlign("left,left,left,left");
        mygrid.setColTypes("ro,ro,ro,ro");
        mygrid.init();
        mygrid.load('test.xml');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use events to customize the grid's behavior. Something like next

```
mygrid.attachEvent("onEditCell", function(stage, id, index){
     if (id%2) return false; //block edit operations
     return true; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also control what is editable on the backend (the process that generates your test.xml data).

I have a fairly elaborate grid where I have the same need.  I accomplished this by first setting up my column types using the setColTypes function.  Majority rules, meaning if most of the rows for a column are edtxt, then I set it to edtxt here...

```
myGrid.setColTypes("link,edtxt,ron,ron,edn,edn,ron[=(c4*c15)+c5],edn,edn,ron[=(c7*c15)+c8],edn,edn,ron[=(c10*c15)+c11],ro,ro,ro");
```

Then for the columns I want to be of a different type I just assign the type while the xml is being build on the back end.  I've removed the server-side code (in this case it was pl/sql that generated this xml)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <row id="100">
        <cell colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;" type="ro">Inspections</cell>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
        <cell type="ro"/>
    </row>
    <row id="1">
        <cell>BLAHBLAH^javascript:gotoRec(1745563)^_self</cell>
        <cell id="jon"/>
        <cell>0</cell>
        <cell>0</cell>
        <cell id="cticol1">100</cell>
        <cell id="cticol2">200</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell id="cticol3">0</cell>
        <cell id="cticol4">0</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell id="cticol5">1.11</cell>
        <cell id="cticol6">2.22</cell>
        <cell/>
        <cell/>
        <cell>10000277932021</cell>
        <cell>444.4</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

So even though some columns are editable, some are a link, etc..., the entire first row will be readonly because I overrode those colTypes in the xml which takes precedence.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write ed as `setcolTypes` to make the column editable.

```
mygrid.setColTypes("ro,ed,ro,ed");
```